# programming language where values and objects are different

Tags: c++, programming-languages, functional-programming, generic-programming

I am trying to get started with the 'Elements of Programming' by Alex Stepanov and Paul McJones. On Page5 last para: They say,

"This book uses a programming language that has no way to describe values and value types as separate from object and object types."

I mean, can someone give an example of a programming language where it is possible to describe values as a separate entity from an object.

Comment: The first example is in the tags... in C or C++ there are values and objects. The terms in C is lvalue for objects, and rvalue for values...

Comment: I'll guess Java but I can't be sure.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I think an object can also be an rvalue (e.g., as in the case of a temporary).

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like they are referring to value types and reference types.  Similar tp the text in this Wikipedia entry ([http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_type_(object-oriented_programming)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_type_%28object-oriented_programming%29))

> Some object-oriented programming languages make a distinction between
>   reference and value types, often referred to as objects and
>   non-objects on platforms where complex value types don't exist, for
>   reasons such as runtime efficiency and syntax or semantic issues. For
>   example, Java has primitive wrapper classes corresponding to each
>   primitive type: Integer and int, Character and char, Float and float,
>   etc. Languages like C++ have little or no notion of reference type;
>   thus, the use of object type is of little interest.

C# has both reference and value types:  [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d43ts61(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d43ts61%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: The book says. "Object type is a pattern for storing and modifying the values in memory". Can you elaborate, a little bit, how reference types (in Java, C#) specify patterns and value-types don't.